# Copy the file 'red' to 'blended' directory in Unix?

Tags: files, filenames, file-copy

[image: refer the image for relative path]

Please tell me how to copy a file using relative path

Comment: The thing with using relative paths is that they are relative to the current working directory.  You have given no indication as to what directory is the current working directory, so it is very difficult to say what the command should look like. It's also a very basic operation and you may want to read up on absolute and relative paths in general, as well as play around a bit on a Unix system to get a feel for how these are or can be used.

Comment: This came up at the same time of year last year, too.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681454/ and what it hyperlinks to.  This _is not_ a request for learning materials.  This is a request for the answers to the exercise questions posed by some learning materials.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following commands to create the above directory structure:

```
$ mkdir -p mydir/{colors,shape,animals}
$ mkdir -p mydir/colors/{basic,blended}
$ touch mydir/colors/basic/{red,blue,green}
$ touch mydir/colors/blended/{yellow,orange,pink}
$ touch mydir/shape/{circle,square,cube}
$ mkdir -p mydir/animals/{mammals,reptiles}
$ touch mydir/animals/mammals/{platypus,bat,dog}
$ touch mydir/animals/reptiles/{snakes,crocodile,lizard}
```

Resulting in this directory structure:

```
$ tree mydir/
mydir/
├── animals
│   ├── mammals
│   │   ├── bat
│   │   ├── dog
│   │   └── platypus
│   └── reptiles
│       ├── crocodile
│       ├── lizard
│       └── snakes
├── colors
│   ├── basic
│   │   ├── blue
│   │   ├── green
│   │   └── red
│   └── blended
│       ├── orange
│       ├── pink
│       └── yellow
└── shape
    ├── circle
    ├── cube
    └── square

7 directories, 15 files
```

Now let's change directory `cd` to this location in your example, and confirm with the `pwd` command that we're where we want to be:

```
$ cd mydir/colors/basic/
$ pwd
/root/mydir/colors/basic
```

Now to copy the file `red` to the directory `blended` you'd use `..` to denote that you want to go up a level in hierarchy. You can test this using the `ls` command first:

```
$ ls ..
basic  blended
```

If we want to go up 2 levels:

```
$ ls ../..
animals  colors  shape
```

So in your case you want to copy to `blended` so that's up 1 level from where the `red` file is, so something like this would list the files in `blended` from the `basic` directory where `red` file is located:

```
$ ls ../blended/
orange  pink  yellow
```

So to copy the `red` file to this location, we simply swap our the `ls` command we've been using for `cp` and confirm with `ls`:

```
$ cp red ../blended/

$ ls ../blended/
orange  pink  red  yellow
```

#### What if we're at the top of `mydir`

If we were in a different location to start, say in the directory where `mydir` exists:

```
$ pwd
/root

$ ls -ld mydir
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Aug 10 08:33 mydir
```

Then the relative location we'd use would be in reference to this location instead. You'd do the following to copy `red` to the `blended` directory. These two commands list out the paths to the respective locations we're dealing with:

```
$ ls mydir/colors/basic/red
mydir/colors/basic/red

$ ls mydir/colors/blended/
orange  pink  yellow
```

This copies the file:

```
$ cp mydir/colors/basic/red mydir/colors/blended/

$ ls mydir/colors/blended/
orange  pink  red  yellow
```