# UNIX - Move the file dog from MAMMALS to SHAPE specify using relative path

Tags: move

As I am new to unix, can somebody tell me how to move a file please. I got an error message as missing destination file operand.

```
mv dog/mammals/shape
```

[image]

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/461782/5132 again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because stackexchange is not a homework solving platform.

Answer (score 4):

[`mv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) takes two arguments:  `SOURCE` and `DEST` where `SOURCE` is the file you want to move in its original location, and `DEST` is where you want to move it.

Arguments are space-delimited.  You provided a command which only gives one argument:

```
mv dog/mammals/shape
```

This says move the file/dir called `shape` from `dog/mammals/` to somewhere that isn't defined.

The correct answer is:

```
mv animals/mammals/dog shape/
```

You can think of this as:   "move file animals/mammals/dog to shape/"

Comment: I have tried what you said sir but still the file is not moved.And the error message is No such directory .Can you please tell me sir.

Comment: In that case, either `animals/mammals/dog` or `shape/` doesn't exist.  Create the former with `mkdir -p animals/mammals && touch animals/mammals/dog` or create the latter with `mkdir shape`.

Comment: $ mkdir -p mydir/{colors,shape,animals}
$ mkdir -p mydir/colors/{basic,blended}
$ touch mydir/colors/basic/{red,blue,green}
$ touch mydir/colors/blended/{yellow,orange,pink}
$ touch mydir/shape/{circle,square,cube}
$ mkdir -p mydir/animals/{mammals,reptiles}
$ touch mydir/animals/mammals/{platypus,bat,dog}
$ touch mydir/animals/reptiles/{snakes,crocodile,lizard}


$ mv mydir/animals/mammals/dog mydir/shape/